# js- changing month num to char in a span class month

Tags: javascript, date

I have a platform that has date picker inside, my problem is addressing the span of class month and after changing it to 3 chars making it a short term of month chars like 01=JAN, 02=FEB, 03=MAR etc.
I've tried all I know but I am a newby with js and dont really know how to address this problem after I changed the date (from date picker) to 2 chars via jquery and then I need to convert it with an array to 3 letters that show the month.

Can some one please guide Me, I've tried some of the things on stack but most of them are manipulations in the datepicker which I cant do because I dont have the path to the js file that implement datepicker on the platform, only address the span directly and change it to a short term of month name.

Heres My fiddle (no css needed so I've just put what I attempted to change with no success):

Trying to Use the array as it is here on the span class month:

```
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "Jun";
month[6] = "Jul";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sep";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";
```

[my snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/subz3r0/s1dd1pc6/1/)

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Did you want `01=JAN` as in your question, or starting with an index of 0 as in your snippet?

Comment: Well I know the index starts from 0 but I want it to "read the int" and if it is equals to 01 it will show JAN, 02 will show FEB and so on thats the problem because in my array I address the index which I cant because I dont have permission to the datepicker js file, thanks for the super fast response

Comment: watch this https://jsfiddle.net/s1dd1pc6/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text from element with class `month`. And replace with with the value from `month` array (subtracting 1)

```js
   
    var month =[];
    month[0] = "Jan";
    month[1] = "Feb";
    month[2] = "Mar";
    month[3] = "Apr";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "Jun";
    month[6] = "Jul";
    month[7] = "Aug";
    month[8] = "Sep";
    month[9] = "Oct";
    month[10] = "Nov";
    month[11] = "Dec";
    
    $(".month").text(month[parseInt($(".month").text()) - 1])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hentry-left">
<div class="entry-date">
<span class="day">11</span>
<span class="month">04</span>
</div>
<div class="featured-image" style="background-image:url(media/about-me-2.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the Array constructor - it's much nicer to use array literal syntax instead.

Once you have the month text from the element, what you need to do is remove the zeros from the start of the string (if any) and then just do the appropriate lookup in your array.

```js
const months = [
  null,
  'Jan',
  'Feb',
  'Mar',
  'Apr',
  'May',
  'Jun',
  'Jul',
  'Aug',
  'Sep',
  'Oct',
  'Nov',
  'Dec'
];

const monthsText = document.querySelector('.month').textContent;
const monthsIndex = monthsText >= 10 ? monthsText : monthsText.slice(1);
console.log('Selected month: ' + months[monthsIndex]);
```

```html
<div class="hentry-left">
  <div class="entry-date">
    <span class="day">11</span>
    <span class="month">04</span>
  </div>
  <div class="featured-image" style="background-image:url(media/about-me-2.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1dd1pc6/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="hentry-left">
<div class="entry-date">
<span class="day">11</span>
<span class="month">04</span>
</div>
<div class="featured-image" style="background-image:url(media/about-me-2.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "Jun";
month[6] = "Jul";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sep";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";

var value = $('.month').text();
$('.month').html(month[parseInt(value)]);
```